# How would you say, "I am emailing you to confirm/remind you of the activity tomorrow"?

Tags: phrases

I was asked by my teacher to email a Japanese student and remind her that we have an activity tomorrow. I am not sure of the structure used to state such a phrase.

My attempt:
こんにちはMさん！
先生は私がMさんと明日の活動を確認しますと聞きました。
よろしくお願いします！

Because I don't want her to think that I'm a weird creeper, I'm trying to say that the teacher asked me to confirm with her.

Answer (score 3):

I'd write:

「こんにちはMさん、先生に頼まれて明日の予定を覚えてるかの確認のメールを送らせてもらってます。返信よろしくお願いします。」

or you can use the word "リマインダー" like:

「こんにちはMさん、先生に頼まれて明日の予定のリマインダーを送っています。返信よろしくお願いします。」

Maybe some people don't know the word.

How to write, especially how polite should do you write depends on the relationship of people, though.